# Trouble with missing attribute in Chef library wrapper cookbook

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I'm wrapping my usage of the Opscode [Java cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/java) with one for my company.

I've created an `attributes\default.rb` file with values specific to my usage.

Despite including a value for the windows package, I keep getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError
------------- 
No resource or method named `windows_package' for `Chef::Recipe "windows"'
```

Here is my `attributes\default.rb` file:

```rb
default[:java][:install_flavor] = "windows"
default[:java][:jdk_version] = "7"
default[:java][:windows][:url] = "http"
default[:java][:windows][:package_name] = "Java VM"
```

I am certain that I have uploaded the updated cookbook to my server, and I am certain that the attributes in this file are being loaded as I was previously receiving errors about missing the required windows package URL until I added it (path edited out above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the windows recipe](https://github.com/socrata-cookbooks/java/blob/master/recipes/windows.rb#L71) of the Java cookbook, there is a call to the [windows_package provider](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/master/providers/package.rb) of the [windows Cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/windows). Thus, the windows cookbook is required for the Java cookbook at least on your platform.

As the Java cookbook doesn't explicitly depend on the windows cookbook (through the `metadata.rb`), it fails at this late stage.

The solution is to add the windows cookbook to your run list.

Comment: I'd add that I added the Windows cookbook by adding include_recipe "windows" to my default.rb recipe file. That way no one using my cookbook will need to know anything about the windows cookbook usage.

Comment: You don't even have to include the `windows:: default` recipe at all (don't know, what it does). Making it a dependency of your own cookbook through `metadata.rb` I'd already enough so that it gets loaded including its libraries.

Comment: Yes, I was incorrect, adding it to metadata.rb was what I meant. Thanks again!